# Answers to "what microcontroller to buy"

Tags: discussion

I'm starting to see questions that ask what microcontroller to choose as a beginner, such as https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1893/158, [Should you learn assembly language for robotics?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1881/158) and https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1896/158.

Do you think we should write a FAQ like [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/912144) for example so we can direct these questions to that FAQ? Maybe one that explains what factors to consider when choosing a microcontroller and what are some of the most common ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I think information like that belongs in the [tag wiki](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/microcontroller/info) for [microcontroller](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microcontroller) rather than as a community wiki question.

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no knowledge of micro controllers, so all I can do is to pass the buck to someone with some background in the area to step forward and start editing.

Comment: Yup, received wisdom on stack exchange now is that using a tag wiki for this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is so much wide and opinion based, even in a wiki there will be opinions just based on "I like these". The question needs to be very clear about what the project needs, and the answer should be technical about why the suggested platform is a better choice.

If it's a beginner just wanting to start, I agree with the OP, so the ask can know some choices in the market and their advantage from a less technical explanation.

Other than that, the choice of a micro-controller, microprocessor, or a platform like Arduino, depending on the project, is so dependent on technical questions that are subjected to high and long discussions.